# Browsers don't parse forms properly

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, html-parsing

I have a rather complex structure. Two `<form>` tags are children of the same tag. They are exactly the same, except they have different id's.

My code looks like this:

```
... complex structure ...
<form>
<div id="container_tag1">
   ... stuff ...
   <div>
   ... stuff ....
       <form id="form1">
            ....
       </form>
   ... stuff ...
   </div>
</div>
... stuff ...
<div id="container_tag2">
   ... stuff ...
   <div>
   ... stuff ....
       <form id="form2">
            ....
       </form>
   ... stuff ...
   </div>
</div>
</form>
... complex structure ...
```

The structure is complex, but as seen above, both forms are on the same level. Their inner content is also exactly the same, but both Firefox and Google Chrome render them improperly.

One of them is show properly in the inspect element view. Just like in the source code. But the another one is parsed totally different: the browser omits the `<form>` tag itself, but adds its inner content to the parent tag, properly parsed.

They are exactly the same, so I really have no idea of whats wrong with my code. The strangest thing is that I've tried replacing the `<form>` tags with `<div>`s and others tags, and everything is parsed and rendered properly. So it really seems like a browser bug, but both Firefox and Chrome parse it this way.

Comment: You cannot nest forms in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to read the standards to get to the obvious answer:

> form must not contain other form elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions